# Read JSON Key Values at run time by passing keys in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I am trying to PARSE Json and pull values based on input key. JSON structure is not same every time
below is sample JSON structure and JSON starts and ends with [] and some time {}

```
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "days": {
            "weekdays": "Friday",
            "weekends": "Sunday",
        },
        "batters": {
            "batter": [
                {
                    "id": "1001",
                    "type": "Regular"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1002",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
            ]
        },
        "topping": [
            {
                "id": "5001",
                "type": "None"
            },
            {
                "id": "5002",
                "type": "Glazed"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

```
{
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "days": {
            "weekdays": "Friday",
            "weekends": "Sunday",
        },
        "batters": {
            "batter": [
                {
                    "id": "1001",
                    "type": "Regular"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1002",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
            ]
        },
        "topping": [
            {
                "id": "5001",
                "type": "None"
            },
            {
                "id": "5002",
                "type": "Glazed"
            },
        ]
    }
```

i tried below code

```
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {

        File InputFolder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//Files//new.json");

        JsonElementFromFile(InputFolder,"name");        
    }

public static void JsonElementFromFile(File FilePath, String key) throws IOException, Exception {
  
   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
   FileReader reader = new FileReader(FilePath);
   JSONArray obj = (JSONArray) parser.parse(reader);  
   for (Object o : obj) { 
      JSONObject json = (JSONObject) o; 
      String jsonKeyValue = (String)json.get(key).toString(); 
      System.out.println(key + " : " + jsonKeyValue); }
  
  }
```

1. above code works when JSON data start with "[" but not working  if it start with "{" , irrespective of any structure I should be able to get value
2. i am able to pull only value from first object keys "id","type","name","ppu" but when i pass key as "days.weekdays" it is not pulling. even if i have more arrays and objectsi should be able to pull just by passing path of key, ex: "batters.batter[0].id" or "batters.batter[1].type"**
3. basically i am looking for reusable code to pull values based on keys passed, dont want to hardcode any values from JSON.

thank you

Comment: You should read the object first and check its type. E.g. if its an instance of `Map` or `JSONObject`, then it's a json object `{ ... }`. If it's a type of `List` / `JSONArray`, then it's a json series `[ ... ]`. If you want to handle both cases, then you'll need to explicitly do so in your code (and not just cast right away).

Comment: you can use google json, do you know as working it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hardcode for different JSON structure, the solution is to use JSON query library.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialize Array**

```
Josson array = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "    {" +
    "        \"id\": \"0001\"," +
    "        \"type\": \"donut\"," +
    "        \"name\": \"Cake\"," +
    "        \"ppu\": 0.55," +
    "        \"days\": {" +
    "            \"weekdays\": \"Friday\"," +
    "            \"weekends\": \"Sunday\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        \"batters\": {" +
    "            \"batter\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": \"1001\"," +
    "                    \"type\": \"Regular\"" +
    "                }," +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": \"1002\"," +
    "                    \"type\": \"Chocolate\"" +
    "                }" +
    "            ]" +
    "        }," +
    "        \"topping\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "                \"id\": \"5001\"," +
    "                \"type\": \"None\"" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"id\": \"5002\"," +
    "                \"type\": \"Glazed\"" +
    "            }" +
    "        ]" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"batters\": {" +
    "            \"batter\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": \"1003\"," +
    "                    \"type\": \"Special\"" +
    "                }," +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": \"1004\"," +
    "                    \"type\": \"DarkChocolate\"" +
    "                }" +
    "            ]" +
    "        }" +
    "    }" +
    "]");
```

**Deserialize Object**

```
Josson object = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"id\": \"0001\"," +
    "    \"type\": \"donut\"," +
    "    \"name\": \"Cake\"," +
    "    \"ppu\": 0.55," +
    "    \"days\": {" +
    "        \"weekdays\": \"Friday\"," +
    "        \"weekends\": \"Sunday\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"batters\": {" +
    "        \"batter\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "                \"id\": \"1001\"," +
    "                \"type\": \"Regular\"" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"id\": \"1002\"," +
    "                \"type\": \"Chocolate\"" +
    "            }" +
    "        ]" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"topping\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"id\": \"5001\"," +
    "            \"type\": \"None\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"id\": \"5002\"," +
    "            \"type\": \"Glazed\"" +
    "        }" +
    "    ]" +
    "}");
```

**Query**

```
System.out.println(array.getString("batters.batter[0].id"));       // 1001
System.out.println(object.getString("batters.batter[0].id"));      // 1001
System.out.println(array.getString("batters.batter[1].type"));     // Chocolate
System.out.println(object.getString("batters.batter[1].type"));    // Chocolate
System.out.println(array.getString("[0].batters.batter[1].id"));   // 1002
System.out.println(array.getString("[1].batters.batter[1].type")); // DarkChocolate
System.out.println(array.getString("batters.batter[3].type"));     // DarkChocolate
```

Answer (score 0):

i found easy way for this question.
using com.fasterxml.jackson , we can pull any any value from JSON ,

```
enter code here
 filepath= place where file stored
 nodepath= path of node 
    File File = new File(filePath);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonTree = objectMapper.readTree(File);
    String value = jsonTree.at(nodepath).asText();
    return value;
```

Comment: Your answer does not address the fact that the input data is sometimes a JSON array and sometimes a JSON object

Comment: irrespective of JSON array or JSON Object, it will pull data from JSON file. node path  for JSON which start with Object should be  "/0/days/weekdays" to pull data and for JSON which start with Array should be "/days/weekdays"